# Simple way to find out if a class is anonymous/object and get the concrete class name from the instance in Kotlin

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, kotlin

When implementing `toString`, etc. I sometimes print/log the concrete class name. Is there an easy/provided way to get this even for anonymous classes? It looks like there are less methods in the Kotlin reflection library than java. Currently, I'm doing it this way:

```
    instance::class.qualifiedName?: 
      instance::class::superclasses.get()[0].qualifiedName)
```

which is really ugly, and I don't know if it's even guaranteed to be correct every time unless the ordering of the list of superclasses is.

Is there a method for kotlin reflection like in `java.lang.reflect` where it's as easy as typing `someClass.isAnonymous()`?

Comment: You can create your own extension function which will hide this 'really ugly' code.

Comment: @Miha_x64 all sarcasm aside that doesn't even address the question.

Comment: hi, what you want to do is get the anonymous class?

Comment: Why not `someClass.java.isAnonymousClass`?

Comment: @hotkey works, but I'm looking for something without JVM i.e. only `kotlin.reflect`